# Eclipse JavaDoc dosen't generate @return automatically

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I think ${tags} can generate @param @return @throws automatically over a method.But my eclipse doesn't generate @return.What's wrong?
[tags label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tt6K.png)

```
/**
 * 
 * @param einvoiceUploadPDF
 * @return
 */
public Map<String, String> buildUploadParamMap(EinvoiceUploadPDF einvoiceUploadPDF) {
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  Map<String, String> paramsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
  paramsMap.put("requestdatas", gson.toJson(einvoiceUploadPDF));
  return paramsMap;
}
```

Comment: The example you show has a @return so what do you think is wrong?

Comment: It hope it to be @return Map,but there is no type information